# Why isn't my new USB 3.0 card / USB 3.0 hard drives working under FreeNAS?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, freenas

I have a Dell Inspiron Desktop 580 into which I have installed a [RocketU 1144A USB 3.0 card](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/usa_new/series_RocketU1144A-Series.htm). The system is running [FreeNAS 8.0.1-BETA4](http://www.freenas.org/), which is based on FreeBSD 8 and supposedly has USB 3.0 support...

I have four [Western Digital MyBook Essential 2TB USB 3.0](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=240) drives. One of them was previously working with this system on a built-in USB 2.0 port before the new USB 3.0 card was installed. Now that the new USB 3.0 card is installed, *the system doesn't see any of the drives regardless of whether they are plugged into the new USB 3.0 card or the built-in USB 2.0 ports!*

It's very odd and doesn't make sense. I know that BSD recognizes the High Point USB card:

```
[root@chef /mnt/Chef/home/jnet]# usbconfig 
ugen0.1: <XHCI root HUB 0x1b21> at usbus0, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=SUPER (4.8Gbps) pwr=SAVE
ugen1.1: <XHCI root HUB 0x1b21> at usbus1, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=SUPER (4.8Gbps) pwr=SAVE
ugen2.1: <XHCI root HUB 0x1b21> at usbus2, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=SUPER (4.8Gbps) pwr=SAVE
ugen3.1: <XHCI root HUB 0x1b21> at usbus3, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=SUPER (4.8Gbps) pwr=SAVE
ugen4.1: <EHCI root HUB Intel> at usbus4, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE
ugen5.1: <EHCI root HUB Intel> at usbus5, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE
ugen4.2: <product 0x0020 vendor 0x8087> at usbus4, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE
ugen5.2: <product 0x0020 vendor 0x8087> at usbus5, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=SAVE
ugen4.3: <DT 101 G2 Kingston> at usbus4, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=HIGH (480Mbps) pwr=ON
ugen5.3: <Dell USB Entry Keyboard Dell> at usbus5, cfg=0 md=HOST spd=LOW (1.5Mbps) pwr=ON
```

Those first four XHCI root HUBs must be the 4 channels on the card... But when I plug one of the USB hard drives in, I don't get an entry under `/dev` and the only message which shows up in `dmesg` or syslog is:

```
ugen0.2: <Unknown> at usbus0 (disconnected)
```

Where `ugen0.2` may be `ugen0.2` - `ugen3.2`.

I am not using any USB hubs. The system is booted off a USB thumb drive, but apart from that, has no other USB devices connected.

I wonder if part of the problem could be that I installed the USB 3.0 card, a 4x PCIe 2.0 card, in the 16x PCIe slot on the motherboard? Yet, the card is recognized by the OS...

---

**UPDATE:** Could this new USB card have somehow *fried* my new drives??? I suddenly can't get them to mount on *any* machine. But like I said, I know one of them was working -- I loaded 1.6 TB of data onto it!

I just plugged a USB 2 drive into the new USB 3 card, and that mounted successfully...

Answer (score 1):

Enough time has passed that I suspect you've already got a solution to this; if so, could you post it?

Otherwise, some starting points:

- You might try using one of `usbconfig`'s options (like `dump_device_desc` or `dump_config` while a drive is connected to see if you can see anything:

  usbconfig -u 0 -a 2 dump_info
- If the product and vendor combo isn't currently recognized by FreeBSD, it can't tell which drive to attach to the device.  I don't know if different devices are presented to the OS for USB2 vs USB3, but it's a possibility.  You might check `/usr/src/sys/dev/usb/usbdevs` for FreeBSD 8 and/or FreeNAS 8.0.1 to see if the devices vendor/product combo is listed (if you can determine them with `usbconfig`, or maybe from `/var/run/dmesg.boot` when the machine is booted with the drives attached.)
- Most USB3 devices are downward-compatible; does the system recognize the drives when you plug them into a USB2 port?

Comment: I should have come back and posted. The answer is **DO NOT USE WESTERN DIGITAL 2TB USB 3.0 DRIVES!!!!!!!!** I went through no less than **nine** of these, **all** of them failed. Drives themselves were fine, the USB enclosures' USB-to-SATA adapters died on me!

Comment: I would say that that is highly unlikely and that there must a a reason that all nine failed. Even if it is only due to an earth loop. But then again, I have been at the failing end of the IBM deathstar drives. (7 out of 8 failed in 3 months).